# Uniform distribution on infinite binary grid

Tags: probability, probability-theory, tessellations

Is there an infinite binary array, so that the distribution of all possible binary $N\times N$ arrays on it will be uniform?

In other words, randomly picked $N\times N$ square will be $\sim\mathrm{Uniform}\left(\{0,1\}^{N\times N}\right)$.

The only direction I can think of is a tesselation with some finite pattern, such that distribution of possible arrays on the pattern itself will be uniform. Plus, all junctions must be ok.

Came up with this problem out of the blue, so any thoughts or pointers are appreciated.

Comment: Do you see a problem with "Each cell is randomly $0$ or $1$, with $50$-$50$ probability"?

Comment: Arthur's suggestion works fine, but if you are looking for the finite patterns you mention then take a look at a [De Bruijn Torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_torus).

Comment: @Arthur I'm looking for a fixed array, not a random variable.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Thanks! Exactly what I wanted to see.

Comment: Of course a De Bruijn Torus works, but you don't need to be quite so strict for your purposes. You are fine also with having a torus where every $N \times N$ square occurs exactly $k$ times for some $k>1$. Maybe there is a simple construction method with $k=N$ or $k=N^2$ or even $k=N^4$.